# Can anybody tell me what "blue" means here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, lyrics

I have a question about the lyrics of "Blue" by Zayn. When he says "I need somebody to love me blue", what does that mean? Where does that expression come from?

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly uncommon expression these days, but "blue" is probably referring to your face turning blue when holding your breath or when you are unable to breathe, so he's basically saying he wants love with enough force that it's as if he can't breathe because of it.